# Jquery "hasClass" not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning all,
I used in my site plaxmove.js and i need to set to distinguish for my pages... I wanna use my plaxmove in my fashion blog only left and right without top and bottom when other pages use all.. My code:

```
if ($('html').hasClass('yu_fashion_layer_4')) {
  $('.yu_fashion_header').on('mousemove', function(e) {

    x = eqH(e)

    $(layer).css({
      left: x
    })

  })
} else {
  $('html').on('mousemove', function(e) {

    x = eqH(e)
    y = eqW(e)

    $(layer).css({
      left: x,
      top: y
    })



  })
}
```

It's not working :(

Comment: share the html you using, also is this class`yu_fashiion_layer_4` present on html or on a particular element?

Comment: Are you trying to register an event only if element is available? If yes, you should look into delegates. `$(document).on('mousemove', '.yu_fashion_header', function(){})`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: We'd have to see the actual HTML you're expecting to detect to have an idea why it isn't matching your jQuery.

Comment: your HTML tag is supposed to have that class?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm just starting to learn jQuery

Comment: @TriSTaR -Then, show us the HTML you're trying to match so we can help you fix your jQuery to work with it.  We're blind here so the only answers you're getting are wild guesses.

Comment: That's not how this site works.  We don't just provide generic tutorials.  We help you solve a specific problem when you've defined the question well enough for us to understand it.  The jQuery doc is always the place to start when learning it and there are thousands of other web sites that discuss jQuery.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok ok man.. don't panic here =)) I just ask when you learn jQuey, if thats tutorials help you become professional, could you share for beginners

Comment: Don't be lazy. [A simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+tutorial) gets you literally millions of results.

Comment: I'm explaining to you how this site works so you can hopefully do better next time.  You see all those down votes on your question?  That's because you didn't follow the proper procedure with your question and when we asked for more detail, you did not provide it.  You got lucky and someone guessed what you apparently wanted, but that was lucky.  Your questions should not require guessing and if you write a good clear question with all necessary information and you respond in a timely fashion when people ask clarifying questions, you will get quick on-target answers and no downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to see if a class is there is your html and not the html tag itself. Use `.find()` for it and check its length.

```
if ($('html').find('.yu_fashion_layer_4').length > 0) {
  $('.yu_fashion_header').on('mousemove', function(e) {

    x = eqH(e)

    $(layer).css({
      left: x
    })

  })
} else {
  $('html').on('mousemove', function(e) {

    x = eqH(e)
    y = eqW(e)

    $(layer).css({
      left: x,
      top: y
    })



  })
}
```

It returns false because your HTML doesn't contain any class, rather some tag in your html will contain that class.

You can also have a selector for the class and then check its length

```
if ($('.yu_fashion_layer_4').length > 0)
```

Comment: Yeaaah) This is what I wanted =)) Thank you

Comment: No problem. Happy to help :)

Comment: Just a pointer, instead of finding, why not just check length directly. `$('.yu_fashion_header').length > 0`

Comment: @Rajesh yes thats also an options. Thanks